# How to animate the color of an Ionicon?

Tags: html, css, svg, ionicons

I want an [ionicon](http://ionicons.com/) (guess its SVG) to iteratively change color. I tried the following, but it only shows the svg icon in purple:

**element**

```
<a class="ion-social-twitter button-home"></a>
```

**css**

```
.button-home {
    fill: #fff;
    -webkit-animation: animation-button 20000ms infinite;
    -moz-animation: animation-button 20000ms infinite;
    -o-animation: animation-button 20000ms infinite;
    animation: animation-button 20000ms infinite;
    font-size: 25vh;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animation-button {
    0%   {fill:red; }
    25%  {fill:yellow; }
    50%  {fill:blue; }
    75%  {fill:green; }
    100% {fill:red; }
}
@keyframes animation-button {
    0%   {fill:red; }
    25%  {fill:yellow; }
    50%  {fill:blue; }
    75%  {fill:green; }
    100% {fill:red; }
}
```

Comment: Your code works if it's used on a `<svg>` element. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjrz0nut/)

Comment: Have changed the question to: how to animate the color of an ionicon. I thought it was a svg icon? For me, it does not work, the colour stays purple.

Comment: ionicon is a font. You could try to animate it's `color`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use *ionicons* as font. Just change the `fill` to `color`, like this -

```
@-webkit-keyframes animation-button {
    0%   {color:red; }
    25%  {color:yellow; }
    50%  {color:blue; }
    75%  {color:green; }
    100% {color:red; }
}

@keyframes animation-button {
    0%   {color:red; }
    25%  {color:yellow; }
    50%  {color:blue; }
    75%  {color:green; }
    100% {color:red; }
}
```

**Here a demo with Bootstrap Glyphicons.**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4q8Lega/)

Comment: @SeanHalls Thanks for notifying, I've fixed the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Its type of icon **font**, So tyr to use `color` *(not `fill`)*

```
.button-home {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-animation: animation-button 20000ms infinite;
    -moz-animation: animation-button 20000ms infinite;
    -o-animation: animation-button 20000ms infinite;
    animation: animation-button 20000ms infinite;
    font-size: 25vh;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animation-button {
    0%   {color:red; }
    25%  {color:yellow; }
    50%  {color:blue; }
    75%  {color:green; }
    100% {color:red; }
}
@keyframes animation-button {
    0%   {color:red; }
    25%  {color:yellow; }
    50%  {color:blue; }
    75%  {color:green; }
    100% {color:red; }
}
```